# Why shouldn't a domain controller use itself as its primary DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

According to [various](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378900%28WS.10%29.aspx) [sources](https://serverfault.com/questions/394804/what-should-the-order-of-dns-servers-be-for-the-network-adapter-of-a-domain-cont), it's considered a best practice to configure a domain controller to use *another* DC as its primary DNS server, and itself as the secondary one. However, according to [other](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b7bf37a2-6e1a-40a8-8d4b-1c15ee9bc0fa/2k8-best-practice-for-setting-the-dns-server-list-on-a-dcdns-server-for-an-interface) [sources](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/07/17/friday-mail-sack-saturday-edition.aspx), the reverse is true, or should at least work anyway without problems.

What are the pros and cons of both solutions?
What risks can each solution have?
What is the potential issue with replication everyone keeps talking about without actually never explaining it?

And, last but not least, ***which solution should be used***?